# RegEx in Python for WikiMarkup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, mediawiki

I'm trying to create a re in python that will match this pattern in order to parse MediaWiki Markup:

```
<ref>*Any_Character_Could_Be_Here</ref>
```

But I'm totally lost when it comes to regex. Can someone help me, or point me to a tutorial or resource that might be of some help. Thanks!'

Comment: Example String: <ref>Sheehan, Sean. Anarchism, London: Reaktion Books Ltd., 2004. p. 85</ref>

Comment: Another example string: <ref>"That is why Anarchy, when it works to destroy authority in all its aspects, when it demands the abrogation of laws and the abolition of the mechanism that serves to impose them, when it refuses all hierarchical organisation and preaches free agreement — at the same time strives to maintain and enlarge the precious kernel of social customs without which no human or animal society can exist." [[Peter Kropotkin]]. [http://www.theanarchistlibrary.org/HTML/Petr_Kropotkin__Anarchism__its_philosophy_and_ideal.html Anarchism: its philosophy and ideal]</ref>

Comment: It's actually WikiMarkup within the <text> node of the xml of the Anarchism page on wikipedia. If I could find an easier way to just parse the wikimarkup, I would, but I'm trying to use re to filter the giant string.

Comment: @JustinBarber It's not really XML, a MediaWiki article is not a valid XML document. So XML parser won't help .

Comment: @svick Ah, I see. It doesn't look like html either. Is it sui generis?

Comment: @svick Do you know an easy way to parse MediaWiki Markup. It would make my life so much easier...

Comment: Is it your wiki? In that case I would build an extension that offers API access to [Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite) data, to provide a more robust way to access references. It would probably be less work than making this regex work, as due to the nature of wikis, the tag could contain *anything*.

Comment: No, it's not my wiki. I'm doing this on a hundreds of thousands of articles in the wikipedia dump: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download).I realize this isn't the best option when pulling out data, but I haven't found a better way to parse MediaWiki MarkUp

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that svick is correct that MediaWiki Markup is not valid xml (or html), then you could use `re` in this circumstance (although I will certainly defer to better solutions):

```
>>> import re
>>> test_string = '''<ref>*Any_Character_Could_Be_Here</ref>
<ref>other characters could be here</ref>'''
>>> re.findall(r'<ref>.*?</ref>', test_string)
['<ref>*Any_Character_Could_Be_Here</ref>', '<ref>other characters could be here</ref>']  # a list of matching strings
```

In any case, you will want to familiarize yourself with [the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (whether or not you use a regex to solve this particular problem).

Answer (score 1):

srhoades28, this will match your pattern.

```
if re.search(r"<ref>\*[^<]*</ref>", subject):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Note that from your post, it is assumed that the * after  always occurs, and that the only variable part is the blue text, in your example "Any_Character_Could_Be_Here".

If this is not the case let me know and I will tweak the expression.

Comment: This also assumes that there will never be any subelements, which certainly seems to be the case given the example above. It's hard to say exactly what the op is looking for, but your option does account for the asterisk. +1

Comment: @JustinBarber You're correct, the expression just matches what srhoades28 asked for. Let's see if s?he changes the requirements.